# Starting a telegram bot without using /start command

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am building a telegram bot that shows a main menu upon starting (using /start). Now, every time I want to start the bot I have to write /start but I want to make it that if the user sent anything (without /start) the bot will start and show the main menu again. I did some research and I couldn't figure it out.

Here is my code:

```
from telegram.ext import CommandHandler, CallbackQueryHandler, Updater
from telegram import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup, ReplyMarkup

API_KEY=''

def start(update, context):
  update.message.reply_text(main_menu_message(),
    reply_markup=main_menu_keyboard())

def main_menu(update,context):
  query = update.callback_query
  query.answer()
  query.edit_message_text(
    text=main_menu_message(),
    reply_markup=main_menu_keyboard())

def main_menu_keyboard():
  keyboard = [[InlineKeyboardButton('Option 1', callback_data='a1'), InlineKeyboardButton('Option 2', callback_data='a2')],
              [InlineKeyboardButton('Option 3', callback_data='a3'), InlineKeyboardButton('Option 4', callback_data='a4')]]
  return InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)

def main_menu_message():
  return 'Hello, How Can I help you??'


updater = Updater(token=API_KEY, use_context=True)
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))
updater.start_polling()
```

[We can see the output of this code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YL5qP.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MessageHandler(Filters.all, callback)` will handle *any* message. See [here](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.ext.messagehandler.html) and [here](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.ext.filters.html#telegram.ext.filters.Filters.all).

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.